# Flask request.files.getlist unable to loop through multiple files

Tags: javascript, python, ionic-framework, flask

I would like to upload multiple files over api, I could get a list of 'FileStorage' when I print out f it looks like: `[<FileStorage: 'case1.npz' ('application/octet-stream')>, <FileStorage: 'case2.npz' ('application/octet-stream')>, <FileStorage: 'case3.npz' ('application/octet-stream')>]`
But somehow every time I go through for loop, it only returns one item. I've looked through documentation and similar questions but the very same situation does not seem to work for me.

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
         for f in request.files.getlist('file'):
              f.save(os.path.join(app.config.get('UPLOAD_FOLDER'), f.filename))
              return 'upload'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return after iterating through all files, you are returning after first iteration

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     for f in request.files.getlist('file')
         f.save(os.path.join(app.config.get('UPLOAD_FOLDER'), f.filename))
     return 'upload'
```